# How to load a new view from controller on ExtJS 5?

Tags: extjs, mvvm

So I am working on a multiple view app based on Sencha ExtJs 5.1.0. And this might be a very silly question. But, how do I load another view from a controller? I am working under the MVVM pattern.

On my index.html I have a div with id="senchaContent", and I am rendering my first view like this:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'EXAMPLE',

    extend: 'EXAMPLE.Application',

    //autoCreateViewport: 'EXAMPLE.view.main.Main'
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('MODIFE.view.main.Main',{
            renderTo: 'senchaContent'
        });
    }
});
```

On the MainController, I am handling the event that should load another view (replacing EXAMPLE.view.main.Main in the #senchaContent Div).

How do I achieve this (destroying the previous view and rendering the new one)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution gonna be to use a panel which handles both. Then you only have to add your new view to the panel.

Checkout my example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/l61

Controller switcher logic:

```
onShowView1 : function() {
    this.getView().removeAll();
    this.getView().add(Ext.create("MyView1"));
},

onShowView2 : function() {
    this.getView().removeAll();
    this.getView().add(Ext.create("MyView2"));
}
```